# Run fail2ban-regex by piping with zcat?

Tags: regular-expression, cat, fail2ban

Normally running the command would go like this:

```
$ fail2ban-regex /var/log/ningx/access.log \
    /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf -v
```

However, I have multiple files that I'd like to parse with the regex test. They have names like `access.log`, `access.log.1`, `access.log.10.gz`, `access.log.111.gz` and so on.

So I tried to use zcat and pipe it like this:

```
$ fail2ban-regex | zcat /var/log/ningx/access.log* \
   /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf -v`
```

but it's not working. How can I pipe it the right way?

Answer (score 2):

You are piping *from* fail2ban *into* the zcat.

Pipes run from left to right. You need to pipe the output of zcat to the input of fail2ban

```
zcat ... | fail2ban-regex ...
```

Comment: From the man page, I'm not sure if `fail2ban-regex` knows how to read from stdin by default (it expects a log entry as a string, or a log file path), so it may be necessary to use `zcat access.log*.gz | fail2ban-regex /dev/stdin /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.